# Create URL from custom attribute in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes

I Have this code to show the Brand on the Single Product Page.
It is working fine, but now I want to create a URL to that Attribute.
The URL is created but it shows the name instead of the SLUG.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'show_brand_product_page' );
function show_brand_product_page() {
global $product;
$showbrand = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_merk' );
echo '<span class="class_merk">Merk: <span class="class_merk"><a href="/merk/' . $showbrand . '" style="color:#40bacb">' . $showbrand . '</a></span></span>';               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'show_brand_product_page' );
function show_brand_product_page() {
global $product;
$showbrand = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_merk' );
$brand_terms = get_the_terms($post, 'pa_merk'); 
foreach ($brand_terms as $term) :
$brand_string .= $term->slug . ' ';
echo '<span class="class_merk">Merk: <span class="class_merk"><a href="/merk/' . $brand_string . '" style="color:#40bacb">' . $showbrand . '</a></span></span>'; 
endforeach;           
}
```